# Please advice a solution for re-using and modifying drum patterns

Tags: drums, midi

In electronic music, loops are used very often - you can take a loop, put into your project, change it somehow and get the work done.

As I'm practicing with my guitar at the moment, I'd like to have something like a loop collection, but for rock\metal styles. Say, 20-30 different drum patterns should cover any demo track - especially if they can be easily modified.

What I want is not just a collection of wav files - I want something like drum patterns, recorded midi events for each type of the drum\cymbal. Then I will be able to choose them, modify, select an appropriate sampler or virtual instrument and concentrate on the guitar playing.

My goal is to simplify the process of creating demo songs (just for myself) - I'll put appropriate drum patterns quickly, instead of long co-operation with a real drummer or (even worse) drawing the notes manually.

I know there are some variations of banks for samplers such as Kontakt, but to be honest I haven't seen any decent bank with not just one-shot samples, but a decent collection of pre-recorded midi patterns. And it's even in electronic styles! For rock\metal that must be even worse.

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: So, is it the actual *patterns* as MIDI files you're looking for? So that you can then use these to trigger samples? If so, you might want to edit the headline of your question, to draw people with that knowledge in.

Comment: BFD3 is a good drum machine with samples that sound very authentic and realistic. Of course, it does come with a price tag...

Answer (score 2):

OK, it seems that with some googling, I found the answer.

Need to search "midi metal drums" or similar. There are some websites selling various collections of loops - in midi - and most of them are compatible with the popular drums software.

They are not free, of course, but it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

EZ Drummer's "Drumkit from Hell" is a rather popular solution to things such as this. Check it out: http://www.toontrack.com/product/dfh-ezx/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Guitar Pro](http://www.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php). The program allows you to create, modify and play back sheet music (using your computer's MIDI sequencer). There is a huge collection of sheet music ("Tabs") available on the web, e.g. on ultimate-guitar.com. Heavy Metal is strongly represented.

An exemplaric work flow that might fit you, is extracting whole/partial drum tracks from your favourite songs (downloaded as tabs from the web), exporting them to MIDI files and re-importing into a DAW of your choice, where you can record your own instrument tracks. As a nice benefit, you can edit/loop/re-arrange the tracks quite easily within GtP before exporting them, using musical notation, as opposed to editing plain MIDI / WAVE in your DAW (which tends to be imprecise).
You would still need a VSTi to play back the MIDI tracks in your DAW though.

To be honest, the software tends to crash rather often, and as a drummer I prefer the outdated version 5 for its superior, numeric note input, but I think any version should fit your specific needs.

Comment: is Guitar Rig something mostly for learning\playing? I'd rather like to compose

Comment: You can use Guitar Pro for composing as well. I like the way you can just preview (i.e. 'play') your changes to a tab immediately. You can compose note-by-note or try MIDI input, which seems to be supported but lacks official documentation.